# Cannot connect to localhost:8000/admin page, Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin, connection-refused

I created a superuser for my site, but when I started the server and tried to connect to the `localhost:8000/admin` page, I got an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` (site cannot be reached) error, and the server stopped running.

urls.py :

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('blog.urls'))
]
```

settings.py :

```py
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

When I start the server, I get the below message:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 17, 2020 - 18:25:44
Django version 3.0.1, using settings 'django_project.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

Comment: Please you need to give us more information. visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What did you use to connect to the server? A browser, or Python command line?

Answer (score 2):

same happened to me. I realized that i defined the path with `/` but i was writing `localhost:8000/admin`

```
path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
```

[image]

I should type `admin/` `localhost:8000/admin/`

Answer (score 0):

Check if the firewall is causing any problem. (If only admin page is causing this problem, then firewall is not causing any probelm.)

Make sure that you have made necessary changes in urls.py and views.py.

Project's `urls.py` should include
`path('admin/', admin.site.urls),` in urlpatterns list.

`settings.py` should include

```
INSTALLED_APPS = ['django.contrib.admin',
              ...#more apps
]`
```

Let me know if this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have checked everything as you've said but the problem still persists.

Comment: @deep_06 Provide more details on the issue, add codes from relevant files so that I can understand the issue better.

Comment: Hi, is there anything else which I have to add. Sorry, I'm very new to Django.

Comment: @deep_06 What happens when you try to run the server by `python manage.py runserver` ?

Comment: The server starts normally.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem .My vpn was causing the problem .Go to chrome menu >setting>advanced settings>here my vpn was controlling the proxy settings and just disabling it fixed the issue .All the best

Answer (score 0):

**Try cleaning browser cache and then refreshing.**

Additionally, in case you have created a custom User model, make sure you

- Register your custom user model in the admin.py of the app where you defined your custom user model (*see* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Admin_site#registering_models)
- In the settings.py, define a variable `AUTH_USER_MODEL = '<app-name>.<custom-user-model-name>'`

Answer (score -2):

you forgot to runserver! python manage.py runserver

Comment: Just to point out, OP said 'When I start the server, I get the below message:'. Seems like they did runserver.